# Solution of $y'=(1+x)(1+y)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Differential equation:

$$y'=(1+x)(1+y)$$

which is: $$y'=y(1+x)+1+x$$.

Like this differential equation I try to solve by:

$$y'(x)=a(x)y+b(x) $$ which solves non-homogenous differential equation.
In this case a(x)=1+x and b(x)=1+x are similar. We have:
$$y(x)=c(x)e^{\int a(x)dx}$$ and $$c(x)=\int b(x)e^{\int a(x)dx}dx$$
I am trying with this method but I can't get solution. What I got is:
$$y(x)=e^{\frac{1}{2}x(x+2)}$$

but this doesn't work. Where is my mistake or is any better way to solve it?

Comment: Try to separate the variables

Comment: @Melina: Said another way, what if you had $\dfrac {dy}{y+1} = (1+x)dx$

Comment: Thnx I got it!!! Stupid mind (N).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice, $y'=\frac{dy}{dx}$. Now, one can easily integrate by separating variables as follws 
$$y'=(1+x)(1+y)$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=(1+x)(1+y)$$
$$\frac{dy}{1+y}=(1+x)dx$$
$$\int \frac{dy}{1+y}=\int (1+x)dx$$
$$\color{red}{\ln|1+y|=x+\frac{x^2}{2}+C}$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\ y'=\frac{d y}{d x}=(1+x)(1+y)$$

Then by separation of variables we get:

$$\ \frac{dy}{1+y}=(1+x)dx$$

And now you can easily integrate both sides